# How to add hypens between specific numbers and characters?

Tags: r, paste, gsub, substr, digits

This is my data set and I want to put hyphens between specific digits and characters.

```
df_t
                  1 2 3 4 5 6         row_names
X2012SGA007930001 1 2 3 4 5 6 X2012SGA007930001
X2012SGA008360001 1 2 3 3 2 6 X2012SGA008360001
X2012SGA009170001 1 2 3 4 5 6 X2012SGA009170001
X2012SGA009180001 1 3 2 3 4 2 X2012SGA009180001
X2012SGA009200001 3 4 5 4 2 1 X2012SGA009200001
X2012SGA009210001 4 5 6 7 8 9 X2012SGA009210001
```

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)



y<- c(str_remove(df_t$row_names, pattern = "X"))
y
is.vector(y)
x<- c(substr( y, start = 1,stop=5))
x
is.vector(x)
z<- c(substr(y, start=6, stop=7))
z

t<- c(substr(y, start=8, stop=12))
t

u<- c(substr(y, start=13, stop=16))
u
```

```
    If I look to x,z,t,u I can see that I seperated it according I want it.
```

```
data<- paste(df_t, col='Genetic', c('x','z','t','u'), sep="-")
```

My question is to become the row_names as following:

```
                          1     2      3    4       5      6         Genetic

                          1     2      3    4       5     "2012S-GA-00793-0001"
                          2     3      4    5       6     "2012S-GA-00836-0001"
                          3     4      4    5       2     "2012S-GA-00917-0001" 
                          2     1      2    3       5     "2012S-GA-00920-0001"                
                          3     3      5    4       7     "2012S-GA-00921-0001"
```

But it doesn't work when I want to put these x,z,t,u together and change the row names to genetic. I tried to use unite function but it doesn't work neither.
Do anyone have any idea how can I add hyphens between specific digits and characters.

Comment: What so you want as the output from the dataframe input?

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
   separate(row_names, letters[1:5],cumsum(c(1,5,2,5,4)))%>%
   unite('Genetics',letters[2:5], sep='-')
                  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 a            Genetics
X2012SGA007930001  1  2  3  4  5  6 X 2012S-GA-00793-0001
X2012SGA008360001  1  2  3  3  2  6 X 2012S-GA-00836-0001
X2012SGA009170001  1  2  3  4  5  6 X 2012S-GA-00917-0001
X2012SGA009180001  1  3  2  3  4  2 X 2012S-GA-00918-0001
X2012SGA009200001  3  4  5  4  2  1 X 2012S-GA-00920-0001
X2012SGA009210001  4  5  6  7  8  9 X 2012S-GA-00921-0001
```

A base R approach: Decided to use pipe and shorten each line fore clarity:

```
paste(dat$row_names, collapse = '\n')|>
   textConnection()|>
   read.fwf(c(1,5,2,5,4), colClasses = 'character')|>
   subset(select = -V1) |>
   c(sep = '-') |>
   do.call(paste, args = _)|>
   cbind(dat, Genetics = _)

                  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6         row_names            Genetics
X2012SGA007930001  1  2  3  4  5  6 X2012SGA007930001 2012S-GA-00793-0001
X2012SGA008360001  1  2  3  3  2  6 X2012SGA008360001 2012S-GA-00836-0001
X2012SGA009170001  1  2  3  4  5  6 X2012SGA009170001 2012S-GA-00917-0001
X2012SGA009180001  1  3  2  3  4  2 X2012SGA009180001 2012S-GA-00918-0001
X2012SGA009200001  3  4  5  4  2  1 X2012SGA009200001 2012S-GA-00920-0001
X2012SGA009210001  4  5  6  7  8  9 X2012SGA009210001 2012S-GA-00921-0001
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the string lengths are consistent, you could vectorize `substr` with `mapply`.

```
dat$genetic <- sapply(dat$row_names, \(x) paste(mapply(substr, list(x), c(2, 7, 9, 14), c(6, 8, 13, 17)), collapse='-'))
dat
#                   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6         row_names             genetic
# X2012SGA007930001  1  2  3  4  5  6 X2012SGA007930001 2012S-GA-00793-0001
# X2012SGA008360001  1  2  3  3  2  6 X2012SGA008360001 2012S-GA-00836-0001
# X2012SGA009170001  1  2  3  4  5  6 X2012SGA009170001 2012S-GA-00917-0001
# X2012SGA009180001  1  3  2  3  4  2 X2012SGA009180001 2012S-GA-00918-0001
# X2012SGA009200001  3  4  5  4  2  1 X2012SGA009200001 2012S-GA-00920-0001
# X2012SGA009210001  4  5  6  7  8  9 X2012SGA009210001 2012S-GA-00921-0001
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(X1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L), X2 = c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), X3 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 6L), X4 = c(4L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 7L), X5 = c(5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 8L), X6 = c(6L, 6L, 
6L, 2L, 1L, 9L), row_names = c("X2012SGA007930001", "X2012SGA008360001", 
"X2012SGA009170001", "X2012SGA009180001", "X2012SGA009200001", 
"X2012SGA009210001")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("X2012SGA007930001", 
"X2012SGA008360001", "X2012SGA009170001", "X2012SGA009180001", 
"X2012SGA009200001", "X2012SGA009210001"))
```